# Fast and simple way to display 3D Surface Mesh

Tags: python, arrays, 3d, points

I have a 2d Numpy array holding 3D points data (2d array is x,y and content is Z data)

I wanted a way to display the data onto a wxPython gui, I searched and managed to get it to work using Mayavi, it works nicely, colors the data, can rotate.

but it takes for every to compile and it will require users of the application to use mayavi.

its seems to me that Mayavi is a bit overqualified for the mission..

so the question is: is there a solution that will 1. not take ~3 min to compile 2. easy to allow for support for other develpoers/users.

thanks!

here is the code im using with Mayavi http://bpaste.net/show/25230/

Comment: How big is your data ?  I generally find mlab/mayavi to be very fast with no noticeable "compile time".

Answer (score 0):

Matplotlib does 3d plots - http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/mplot3D